# Transparent JTexfield with background image

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

I wanted to know how to set an image to a **`JTextField`** if this is **transparent**, or how to make my `JTextField` look like this:

[image: JTextField's background image]

Here's how I make my field transparent, but I can't set its background image:

```
//Step 1: Remove the border line to make it look like a flat surface.  
field.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.white, 0));  

//Step 2: Set the background color to null to remove the background.  
field.setBackground(null);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All Swing components have a concept of transparency, which is controlled via the use of `opaque` property.  Setting the background to `null` tents to rest the background color of the field to it's UI default.

Having said that, some components can ignore this (partially or completely).  In these case we can cheat...

In the following example, set the field transparent via the `opaque` property, this is important, as the `RepaintManager` will not paint areas behind components unless they are transparent, and use a fully transparent background color.

[image: Field]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class TestTextField {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestTextField();
    }

    public TestTextField() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JTextField field = new JTextField(20);
                field.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0));
                field.setOpaque(false);

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.RED);
                frame.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
                frame.add(field);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

**Updated based on comments...**

This is a very specific example designed to provide a direct answer to the presented problem.  Basically, what this does is creates a custom border and uses an `Image` to render the "border"

[image: Border example]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.border.AbstractBorder;
import javax.swing.border.Border;
import javax.swing.border.MatteBorder;

public class TestTextField {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestTextField();
    }

    public TestTextField() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JTextField field = new JTextField(20);
                try {
                    BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/FieldBorder.png"));
                    field.setBorder(new ImageBorder(img, 8, 6));
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
                frame.add(field);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class ImageBorder implements Border {

        private BufferedImage img;
        private int bottomMargin;
        private int leftMargin;

        public ImageBorder(BufferedImage img, int leftMargin, int bottomMargin) {
            this.img = img;
            this.bottomMargin = bottomMargin;
            this.leftMargin = leftMargin;
        }

        @Override
        public void paintBorder(Component c, Graphics g, int x, int y, int width, int height) {
            g.drawImage(img, x, y + height - img.getHeight(), c);
        }

        @Override
        public Insets getBorderInsets(Component c) {
            return new Insets(0, leftMargin, bottomMargin, 0);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isBorderOpaque() {
            return false;
        }

    }

}
```

Now, this could also be done using custom painting within the custom `Border` instead, but was quicker this way ;)

**Another option...**

Is to simply use a `JPanel` and add the field and a `JLabel` holding the border outline together, for example...

[image: CompoundField]

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.border.Border;

public class TestTextField {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestTextField();
    }

    public TestTextField() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JTextField field = new JTextField(20);
                field.setBorder(null);

                JPanel fieldPane = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
                fieldPane.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
                GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
                gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
                gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
                gbc.insets = new Insets(0, 8, 0, 0);
                fieldPane.add(field, gbc);

                try {
                    BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/FieldBorder.png"));
                    gbc.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0);
                    fieldPane.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(img)), gbc);
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
                frame.add(fieldPane);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

But this will come down to needs and requirements...

**Text field with a background**

[image: Textfield with background]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.text.Document;

public class TextFieldBackground {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TextFieldBackground();
    }

    public TextFieldBackground() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                TextFieldWithBackground field = new TextFieldWithBackground(40);
                try {
                    field.setBackgroundImage(ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/clouds.jpg")));
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
                frame.add(field);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TextFieldWithBackground extends JTextField {

        private BufferedImage bg;

        public TextFieldWithBackground() {
        }

        public TextFieldWithBackground(String text) {
            super(text);
        }

        public TextFieldWithBackground(int columns) {
            super(columns);
        }

        public TextFieldWithBackground(String text, int columns) {
            super(text, columns);
        }

        public TextFieldWithBackground(Document doc, String text, int columns) {
            super(doc, text, columns);
        }

        public void setBackgroundImage(BufferedImage bg) {
            this.bg = bg;
            setOpaque(bg == null);
            repaint();
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            if (bg != null) {
                int x = 0;
                int y = (getHeight() - bg.getHeight()) / 2;
                while (x < getWidth()) {
                    g.drawImage(bg, x, y, this);
                    x += bg.getWidth();
                }
            }
            super.paintComponent(g);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: nice way to do it, but actually what i need is this ->https://www.dropbox.com/s/ef6tdb7hzzqacpi/Sin%20t%C3%ADtulo.png

Comment: Well, that's not a transparent field :P

Comment: No, ignore the background, what i need is a textfield with the blue line without borders and background

Comment: Nice!, but now i have another problem, when i write something, the text is below the image, so that i can't see what i write, could you please help me, purposely thanks for everything

Comment: How do you mean it's "below" the image?

Comment: The image cover the text. Just one more question, if i want a background image in a textfield what should i do?

Comment: I'm going to need an example.  Painting a background image into a text field is not a trival matter